# Limsup of product of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

A sequence $\langle X_n\rangle\rightarrow x > 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$; $\limsup(Y_n) = y$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$.
Show that $\limsup(X_nY_n) = xy$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$.

My thinking:
Consider the cases when $y < 0$ and when $y\geq0$. Any help for a proof?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have to separate the cases $y < 0$ and $y \ge 0$.

I would go back to the definition of $\limsup$:

- Take $Z^\prime > xy$ and prove than for all $n$ large enough $x_n y_n < Z^\prime$.
- And for $Z^{\prime \prime} <xy$ you can find an infinite number of integers $n$ with $Z^{\prime \prime} <x_n y_n$

Comment: May I ask you details for this proof? Thanks